# Combine tax_query and meta_query in query_posts()

Tags: php, wordpress

I try to get custom posts with predefined meta value.The query return nothing.

```
    $args = array
    (
        'post_type' => 'item',
        'nopaging' => true,
        'tax_query' => array
        (   array
            (
            'taxonomy' => $taxonomy,
            'field' => 'term_taxonomy_id',
            'terms' => $term_id
            )
        ),
        'meta_query'  => array(
            array(         
                'key'     => 'from_import',  
                'value'   => '1', 
            )
        )
    );
    $posts = query_posts( $args );
```

When I remove meta_query or tax_query it works fine. How I can combine it?

Answer (score 0):

This should fix your code I believe. I haven't actually run it but try it out. You had one extra 'array()' in each of them.

```
    $args = array
    (
        'post_type' => 'item',
        'nopaging' => true,
        'tax_query' => array
        (
           'taxonomy' => $taxonomy,
           'field' => 'term_taxonomy_id',
           'terms' => $term_id
        ),
        'meta_query'  => array(
           'key'     => 'from_import',  
           'value'   => '1'
        )
    );
    $posts = query_posts( $args );
```

Comment: Thank you, but without second arrow `tax_query` query can't filter result.

Answer (score 0):

I just run through this, here's a working snippet I'm using for my scenario, tweak as needed to match your needs.

```
// Bring post from the global context (if not present already).
global $post;

// Define the post_type's to query for.
$post_types = array( 'event', 'post', 'book' );

// Do the weird query. 
// Play with, or add arguments as needed https://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Query
$results = WP_Query(
        array(
            'post_type' => $post_types,
            'tax_query' => array(
                array(
                    'taxonomy' => 'category',
                    'terms' => wp_get_post_categories( $post->ID )
                )
            ),
            'meta_query' => array(
                'relation' => 'OR',
                array(
                    'key'     => 'presenters_people',
                    'value'   => $post->ID,
                    'compare' => 'LIKE'
                ),
                array(
                    'key'     => 'author',
                    'value'   => $post->ID,
                    'compare' => 'LIKE'
                )
            )
        )
    );
```